# Why is the function $f: \ell^2(\mathbb{N}) \to f(\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ defined by $f(\{a_n\}) = \{a_n/n\}$ not have continuous inverse?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

In the lecture notes, it is claimed that if $X = \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$, the space of real sequences with $\sum_{i=1}^\infty |a_n|^2 < \infty$, then the function

$$f(\{a_n\}_n) = \{a_n/n\}_n$$

does not have a continuous inverse at $0$. That is, $f^{-1}$ is not continuous at $0$ where $0$ is the $0$ sequence.

Comment: great ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac 1 n e_n \to 0$ but $f^{-1} (\frac 1 n e_n) =e_n$ which does not tend to $0$.

[$e_n$ is the sequence with $1$ at the n-th place and $0$ elsewhere].

Comment: Thank you! It feels trivial now that you say it.